# How can I safely test Redstone contraptions with support for Redstone Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to experiment and test designs on a computer too weak to run Minecraft at any reasonable speed, and without distractions like night time, mobs blundering onto railway tracks, Endermen dismantling my construction, and so on.

Is there a way to run Redstone tests/simulations that support the 1.5 features? I understand analog features like comparators might take a while, but I'd like to experiment with circuits involving Redstone Blocks pushed around by pistons, and I can't find any simulators online that currently support them.

Comment: For experiments, you can always use Sandbox modes (Creative + superflat). Currently, there is - to my knowledge - no simulator for redstone, as a) there *is* a way to do this easily in-game now and b) the redstone rework still seems less-than-optimal and might change yet again.

Comment: The best redstone simulator is Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no simulators that support 1.5 redstone functions. You could instead consider running a toned down version of Minecraft on Superflat, Peaceful, Optifine, etc.

Comment: Also/alternatively: `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false`, `/time set day`, and `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`.

Comment: Yes, those will help too :)